# How to use Delphi conditional compilation to generate exe or dll?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, conditional-compilation

I am using Delphi XE2 and I have a program that can be compiled as Win32 EXE or ISAPI DLL. That works fine.

However my problem is how to conditionally compile.

```
{$include MyConditionals.Inc}

{$ifdef ISAPISERVER}
library
{$else}
program
{$endif}
  MyProgram;
```

That works, but the FILE extension is getting wrong. It generates an EXE extension always. I need that when selected the library condition to have the DLL extension generated.

How can easily change the condition and have the right extension?

Comment: I think it is better to use two separate projects for this

Comment: @VitaliyG I was doing that, however everytime I add a new unit, I have to update both project, and I add many units, it is boring doing that.

Comment: Whether it is *boring* or not, it is the **correct** thing to do. You must use separate projects for different output types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree with doing correct things. I meant boring because more automated things are less trouble, less problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use a conditional compilation to change the extension of the binary. The extension of the file is set in the build process depending of the value (Application,  Library, Console) for the `AppType` entry in the .dproj file. My recommendation is create a build batch file for the dll and another for the application.

Comment: Here is what I have found so far: If I put my $define on the project file instead using an INCLUDE, Delphi understands the change of project type and switch between EXE and DLL. But only works when the project is opened on the expected output already set.

Comment: I was trying this way because mostly of development and testing is done using EXE output, some customers use this output, but I have 2 other possibilities. However to compile on the other projects I need to update the USES clause of the project with the changes that happened on the main project. And there are days when I need to do that several times per day. I am fine with more than one project, but wanted to have an "integrated" USES clause.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, IDE itself is preventing you from doing that. I successfully produced both executable binary and dynamic-link library from the following source:

```
{$IFDEF CGI}program{$ELSE}library{$ENDIF} test;

begin
end.
```

using `dcc32 -DCGI test.pas` and `dcc32 -DNSAPI test.pas` commands.

Delphi IDE thinks what it "owns" the project source, so it is advised against placing conditional directives there even in newer MSBuild-based IDEs.

Comment: you right, it seems it is capable to do some of the automation, but this is not expected, the IDE really owns the project source

Comment: @eelias, you could also try `$E` directive and see if it of any use in your case.